# Which phrase should be used in the following sentences?

Tags: grammar

In the following sentences, which phrase should be used?

> 1. After the matriculation exam, she went on to attend university.
> 2. After the matriculation exam, she went on attending university.
> 3. After the matriculation exam, she went on for attending university.

Comment: Incidentally, in the US we don't have matriculation exams, so all of the sentences sound a little strange to a US English speaker!  It would be perfectly normal to refer to a matriculation exam taking in a country that does have them, though.

Answer (score 2):

**These three sentences have different meanings. The first sentence is likely the one you want.**

---

> 1. After the matriculation exam, she went on to attend university.

This sentence simply means, after the exam - a resulting action was that she started attending the university.

This is likely the sentence you are wanting, it is a common way to say that because of A, a person then did B.

---

> 1. After the matriculation exam, she went on attending university.

Here, "went on " means that she continued doing it. This sentence suggests that she was already studying at university when she took the matriculation exam - and then continued to do so afterwards.

From the context of matriculation exam, it's unlikely you are wanting to use this sentence. However, it does have a meaning.

---

*For reference, please do not actually use 3 - it is ambigous, not particularly correct and not common.*

> 3. After the matriculation exam, she went on for attending university.

This sentence is not well formed, or at least so uncommon it would be hard to argue that it's fully correct.

Technically, it could mean that after the matriculation exam she went on [something] for (in order to, or because of) her attending university.

It potentially could be:

> [Talking about a train journey] After the matriculation exam, she went on [the train that was designed] for her attending university.

or

> [Talking about going live on TV] After the matriculation exam, she went on [the live TV for an interview] because she was attending university.

Realistically, neither of these will be used - but hopefully it gives an idea of what that grammar could potentially mean.

*Again - please do not use this version.*